# Where can I find how the Ethereum protocol calculates transaction fees, supply issuance, and other key components?

Tags: transactions, protocol, code

I would like to learn how different components of the Ethereum protocol are calculated. Where can see how these and other elements?

Is there a code database that a final code source that I can refer to?

Answer (score 1):

The full specification of the EVM can be found in the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).

The Ethereum ecosystem has many [client implementations](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#execution-clients) of the Yellow Paper.  The most widely used client is probably [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) (this [video](https://youtu.be/bEUtGLnCCYM) is a good introduction to their codebase).
Further there exists an [execution client specs](https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs) written in Python.

Comment: Also https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs and https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs